# grid layout positioning of components dynamically

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have a  composite having gridlayout of 5 columns and it contains
some buttons. Now is it possible to add any other control to
a specific location of GridLayout? for example, I want to add
one TextField at first row of third column i.e in place of Button3
and Button 3 should come down to the last row i.e after button7.
Any type of dynamic positioning is possible in GridLayout?

```
package zrcp;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

   public class LayoutExample {

    protected Shell shell;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            LayoutExample window = new LayoutExample();
            window.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 300);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.setText("Button1");

        Button btnNewButton_1 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_1.setText("Button2");

        Button btnNewButton_2 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_2.setText("Button3");

        Button btnNewButton_3 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_3.setText("Button4");

        Button btnNewButton_4 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_4.setText("Button5");

        Button btnNewButton_5 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_5.setText("Button6");
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

        Button btnNewButton_6 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton_6.setText("Button7");
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

GridLayout won't do this out of the box, but it will render the buttons in the order that the parent composite returns them, so you could create a custom composite that sorts the buttons and add them to that rather than directly to the Shell:

```
class SortedComposite extends Composite {
    private Comparator<Control> comparator; // TODO Create this

    public SortedComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
    }

    @Override
    public Control[] getChildren() {
        Control[] children = super.getChildren();
        Arrays.sort(children, comparator);
        return children;
    }

}
```

The `setData` method on the buttons would provide a good way to attach data to them that the comparator can use to sort them.